# Change input value on pageload if URL contains string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change an input field's value based on the URL in the address bar. If the URL contains "sometext" then the input field value should be "Search by keyword or catalogue number" and if not, the value should be "Search by keyword". When the input box is clicked, the placeholder text should go away.

There are no console errors but the input field text is not being changed.

```
window.onload = onPageLoad();
function onPageLoad() {
var url = parent.document.URL; //Using parent.document.URL as this in within an iFrame.
    if (url.indexOf("sometext") > -1) {
        $("#SearchValue").val("Search by keyword or catalogue number")
    }
    else {
        $("#SearchValue").val("Search by keyword")
    }
}

<input onfocus="if(this.value.indexOf('Search by keyword') > -1){this.value = '';}" size="50" value="Search by keyword" name="SearchValue">
```

Comment: `this` in the `onfocus` event is referring to the DOM object, try using `this.value.indexOf()` instead.

Comment: @mark.hch that has fixed part of the issue (updated original post to reflect this). However, the input text is still not changing.

Comment: If you didn't see my previous comment before deleting (I deleted because the two links I provided didn't do what I wanted since the result pane of jsfiddle uses a different URL than the parent window) - try using `document.URL` instead of `parent.document.URL`.

Comment: @mark.hch I'm having to use parent.document.URL as this is used inside an iFrame. I've tested this part and it works okay.

Comment: I don't understand then. What input text isn't changing if `this.value.indexOf()` fixed the `onfocus` event, and your `onPageLoad` function works appropriately?

Comment: @mark.hch - The strange thing is that the page doesn't recognize "sometext" until a postback occurs (after searching for text). I'm guessing it has something to do with the iFrame.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200736/discussion-between-shane-and-mark-hch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you don't need to mess with the value of the input control, there is a `placeholder` attribute you can use for that:

**HTML**

```
<input size="50" placeholder="" name="SearchValue" id="SearchValue">
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = onPageLoad();

function onPageLoad() {
  var url = document.location.href;

  if (url.indexOf("sometext") > -1) {
    $("#SearchValue").attr("placeholder", "Search by keyword or catalogue number");
  }
  else {
    $("#SearchValue").attr("placeholder", "Search by keyword");
  }
}
```

You can try it here: https://zikro.gr/dbg/html/test.html?sometext

Comment: I'm aware of the placeholder attribute but was trying to find a solution without having to edit the input field as that wasn't my code. However, I'm accepting this answer as it's a solution that works.